Prediction vs confidence intervals using random forest / an ensemble of estimators
Given a random forest (or any other ensemble) where each of the $i=1..n$ trees/base estimators is trained by minimizing the mean squared error, then each tree/base estimator prediction  $\hat{Y}_i(x) = \hat{E}[Y|X=x]$ tries to estimate the conditional mean. The ensemble estimator would produce a final estimated conditional mean by averaging over the base estimators again $\hat{Y}_{RF} = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n \hat{Y}_i(x)$ (because this reduces $Var[\hat{Y}_{RF}(x)]=\frac{1}{n^2} Var[\sum_i \hat{Y}_i(x)] \approx Var[\hat{Y}_i (x)]/n$, for uncorrelated estimators..., but this is idealized, probably the estimators are correlated so correction terms are missing )!
Computing the variance over tree predictions $"\hat{Var}[\hat{Y}_i]"=\frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^n\left( \hat{Y}_i(x)-\overline{\hat{Y}_i(x)}\right)^2$ gives the spread of a confidence interval of the conditional mean and not a prediction interval, right? (Assuming that the interval could be parametrized by a mean and variance...) The prediction interval $I$ would instead be given by $Pr(Y∈I∣X=x)=1−α$
I just had a discussion here with somebody and want to be sure that I am right...

I appreciate that the answers to this question  Random forests confidence intervals and prediction
mention a confusion between prediction and confidence intervals, but it is not direcly answering my question here since it applies the jackknife method.
I also appreciate the other hints in the answers of how to construct a prediction interval:

Quantile regression (e.g. with quantile random forests)
Computing the prediction interval from the residuals (similarly to the idea of residual bootstrap)


I think this is the paper you need to look at. From the abstract: "To our knowledge, this is the first set of results that allows any type of random forest, including classification and regression forests, to be used for provably valid statistical inference." https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/01621459.2017.1319839

Thanks for the paper, I will have a closer look, maybe you can point me to the relevant section. My main claim/question where I want to be sure is that computing the standard deviation over all tree predictions of a RF will not produce a measure of scale of the possible observed values (i.e. not a parametrization of a prediction interval, if this could be parametrized by a mean and a standard deviation). What we would get is a parametrization of a confidence interval (if the interval could be parametrized by a mean and a standard deviation).

The paper I cite establishes asymptotically valid confidence intervals. See especially section 3 and theorem 1. This requires "honest" trees, typically establishes through double sampling, subsampling rather than bootstapping ("bagging"), etc. and several regularity conditions. I'm pretty sure the process you outline will not provide valid confidence intervals. Here is the ungated version. https://arxiv.org/pdf/1510.04342

Sounds good. Still to be precise: if we compute the standard deviation over the predictions of all trees, then we get confidence intervals (with possibly really bad coverage), right? And this surely is not useful for obtaining prediction intervals. Right? (Let uns not confuse confidence and prediction intervals here)

Sorry, I don't know. I don't think this procedure would have any statistical guarantees as a confidence interval or prediction interval but whether or not it would be "useful" for a particular case, I think you'd just need to runs some simulations.

I simulated with a 1d linear toy model and the result is that the above interval obtained by computing the standard deviation over the individual tree predictions is a confidence interval, not a prediction interval (which makes sense because we get to estimate the width of the sampling distribution of the conditional mean estimators)
